# Uber Webhooks in Limited Access Mode

Tags: uber-api

We are testing Uber Webhooks. The Webhooks are working well for requests made in Sandbox environment.

We understand that some of the endpoints that require Privileged Scope can be invoked in "Limited Access" mode as long as the user is one of the registered developers.

Is this true for Webhooks also? If one of the registered developers takes a real Uber ride, will the Webhook get invoked?

We took a real Uber ride but the Webhook was not invoked, so wanted to check with the community to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should see the same webhooks behavior for any two users who have granted your app the same set of scopes.

Are the registered developer's rides being requesting via the external API or through the app? If it's through the app, webhooks will only be triggered provided that the registered developer granted your app the `all_trips` scope from his/her Uber account. With the `request` scope webhooks are only triggered for rides requested via the external API.

(Context for other readers: Both the `all_trips` and `request` scopes are "privileged", meaning that Uber must whitelist an app before users can grant those scope to it. As OP mentions, there is an exception for registered developers, who can grant privileged scopes to the app they're registered for.)

Comment: The registered developer's rides are triggered through the app and the developer has granted the app "all_trips" scope. We have not yet requested 'Full Access' for our app. Do you think we should have our webhooks invoked in this scenario?